# RxJs ReplaySubject does not replay on Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs5

I am on Ionic2/RC0 and I am implementing a user service for my application.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    UserWhatever: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>();



    constructor(private _util: UtilService,
        private _app: AppService,
        private _http: Http) {
        console.log("I am UserService. Just got created")

        this.UserWhatever.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log("User service got a USER");
            }
        )


    }

    login(element) {
        return this.getToken(element).flatMap(
            (data) => {
                return Observable.forkJoin([Observable.of(data),
                this.readUser(data)
                ]);
            }
        ).map(data => {
            localStorage["jwt"] = data[0];
            this._util.sendToast("logged");
            console.log("Http call received a USER")
            let guser: User = data[1];
            console.log("Called next ")
            this.UserWhatever.next(guser)
        });
    }
```

As soon as I got the full response from the login() observable inside my HomeComponent I send the user to the DashboardComponent

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    subs() {
        this._user.UserWhatever.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log("Login Component got a Replayed USER");
            })
    }


    login() {
        this.isDisabled = true;
        this._user.login(this.loginForm)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.subs()   
                this.nav.push(DashboardPageComponent);
            }    
    }
```

Where I subscribe to the ReplaySubject from my userService. Here its where the problems appear.It does not replay the subject by the time of its subscription. It all works fine if I happen to call next() again on the ReplaySubject.

```
export class DashboardPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    public user: User;


    constructor(private _app: AppService,
        private _device: DeviceService,
        private _user: UserService,
        private _store: Store<any>,
        private _nav: NavController) {
        console.log("Dashboard component")
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this._user.UserWhatever.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.user = data;
                console.log("Dashboard finally received a User")
                console.log(data)
            }
        )
    }
```

Its all working as a regular Rxjs.Subject() but I need the replay feature. I am on rxjs.beta-12

#### Updated Logs

```
I am UserService. Just got created
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
Http call received a USER
Called next 
User service got a USER
Login Component got a Replayed USER
I am UserService. Just got created
Dashboard component
```

Comment: I like question title `....doesn't replay`...;) he he !!!

Comment: Are you sure that the *same* `UserService` instance is being injected into `DashboardPageComponent` and `LoginComponent`?  Is it possible `DashboardPageComponent` gets a *new* instance (and thus new empty `ReplaySubject`)?

Comment: @Brandon How would I be sure? I am importing from the same file if thats what you mean. I am pretty sure thats what is happening but do not know why. Subscriptions work if I happen to call next afterwards

Comment: put a console.log statement in the UserService constructor and see how many times it prints.

Comment: @Brandon looks like `this.nav.push(DashboardPageComponent);`create another another UserService when it gets created. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: But thats not the issue. Instead of nav.push I am calling a function that subscribe to the ReplaySubject. And I dont get anything

Comment: show your updated code where you subscribe instead of calling `nav.push`.

Comment: I am going to update the question!  @Brandon thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124918/discussion-between-cesco-and-brandon).

Comment: @Brandon Updated question now shows that rxjs works. But Ionic nav.push reinstanciate the UserService so I do not get expected replay as you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code (which is essentially correct) and testing, your problem is that the `UserService` is getting recreated for each component that needs it.  You need to make it a "singleton service", which just means a single instance will get shared with all components that need it.

I am not familiar with Ionic.  Here's [one thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-create-a-singleton-service/40113/6) you can try.  If it doesn't help, I suggest you open a second SO question asking how to make your UserService a singleton in Ionic.

Apparently changing your `DashboardPageComponent`'s constructor to declare the `_user` property to be public instead of private will allow Ionic to inject the same instance instead of making a new one.  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rc0-typescript-private-vs-public-keyword/64863

Comment: Got it now! `constructor(private _user:UserService)` should be `constructor(public _user:UserService)`. I you care to edit your answer to add this I would accept as the correct answer

Comment: I have renamed the question to be Ionic2 specific

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rc0-typescript-private-vs-public-keyword/64863

Comment: @CESCO ok I added a paragraph that hopefully captures what you discovered.